# What's the difference between [sailplane] and [glider] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

For me, it looks like both tags ([gliders](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider) and [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane)) are similar and active (last question active less than a month ago). I fail to see the difference.

What are the criteria to know if a question falls into one category rather than the other?

---

> > **Notice:** the formal request is now here: [tag synonyms merging: sailplane and gliders](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892)

Answer (score 6):

It's the same as the difference between a sailplane and a glider. See: [What is the difference between a glider and a sailplane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/41111/what-is-the-difference-between-a-glider-and-a-sailplane)

(By the way, that question that I linked ought to be reopened. I just edited and cast a vote to reopen it.)

In particular, a glider is *any* aircraft designed primarily for unpowered flight. A sailplane, on the other hand, is a glider with conventional control surfaces (ailerons, elevator, and rudder—as opposed to, say, a paraglider or a hang glider) which is designed for staying aloft in updrafts (as opposed to a cargo glider, which is intended to simply travel a reasonable distance and then land).

Although the concepts are different, I'm not sure both *tags* need to exist. Perhaps we could get by with just the [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider) tag and do away with [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane).

Comment: Your answer confirm what I thought. Do I have to write anew question here to get rid of one of the tag?

Comment: @ManuH Sorry for the late response. Yes, if I were you, I would write a new meta post suggesting the deletion of the tag you think should be deleted.