# tag synonyms merging: sailplane and gliders

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

As suggested by this [answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3888/3394), I would like to either delete the [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane) tag or merge it with [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider). Can anyone make it ? (I don't have enough power/rights)

Answer (score 2):

From the post you link

> In particular, a glider is any aircraft designed primarily for unpowered flight. A sailplane, on the other hand, is a glider with conventional control surfaces.

I personally don't see how this can be interpreted to mean that glider and sailplane are synonyms.

Comment: I also disagree with the proposed merge. [Wikipedia considered and decided against a similar merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Glider_(aircraft)#Merge_article_with_Glider_.28sailplane.29_article) which im not saying we *must* follow, but is a useful data point. We also have a question [right here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/41111/what-is-the-difference-between-a-glider-and-a-sailplane) on the difference - and being the answer was NOT that there is no difference, we should continue to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 0):

I second the motion to merge..