# What is the difference in tag usage of [fixed-wing] vs. [airplane]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

What is the difference in tag usage of [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing) x57 vs. [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) x72?

If fixed-wing is to differentiate unpowered, is it [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane) then? Which has its own tag, and has been proposed and voted for merging with [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider):

- [What's the difference between [sailplane] and [glider] tags?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3887/14897)
- [tag synonyms merging: sailplane and gliders](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892/14897)

In other words, are there questions where someone would need [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing) that they can't use [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) or [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider)?

---

If no difference, or if the difference can be overlooked for simplicity, then kindly propose which way the synonym should be in the same answer, so the top-voted answer can also serve as the request for applying said synonym.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane):

> An airplane or aeroplane (informally plane) is a powered, fixed-wing aircraft that is propelled forward by thrust from a jet engine, propeller or rocket engine.

From the tag info page for [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane):

> A heavier-than-air fixed-wing aircraft propelled by one or more engines.

So [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing) is the more generic term, which applies to both [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane)s and [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane)s. Therefore, [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing) is **not** a synonym of either.

We might however want to add a more detailed tag info to [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing), which currently only has an excerpt, to clarify the difference.

---

Regarding the usage on this site: I would recommend being specific (i.e. using [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) or [sailplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailplane)) whenever possible, e.g. this question:

[Why are propeller driven aircraft commonly built with a higher wing aspect ratio and a straighter wing angle?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67825/why-are-propeller-driven-aircraft-commonly-built-with-a-higher-wing-aspect-ratio)

is currently tagged [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing), but should really use [airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) because it is clearly about powered aircraft. But questions, where it makes no difference, should be tagged [fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing) like this one:

[Why do Wingtip Vortices affect the upwash ahead of the aerofoil?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66406/why-do-wingtip-vortices-affect-the-upwash-ahead-of-the-aerofoil)

Here, it makes absolutely no difference whether or not the aircraft is powered or not.

Comment: Thanks. By synonym I'm referring to their usage here on the site. Are there questions where someone would need [fixed-wing] that they can't used [airplane] or [glider]?

Comment: @ymb1 I understand. I included my opinion regarding the usage on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the update and finding examples, so +1. It must have been hard as from what I see, those two tags are applied almost randomly :) And since those two tags account for 127 questions where one of them and not the other is used, it's not an easy fix.

Comment: I don’t see your argument for why that question shouldn’t be tagged fixed wing.

Comment: @Notts90 That question is about the difference between propeller driven aircraft and jet aircraft, both of which are **airplanes** (because they are powered), which is more specific than **fixed-wing** because that also includes sailplanes.

Comment: @Bianfable thanks, in that case I’d suggest tagging both.

Comment: @Notts90 OK, feel free to add that as an answer. I thing tagging both is redundant. I would prefer to only tag one.